# Construct Solution with Multiple WCF Applications

Tags: c#, wcf

We currently have a solution with only one WCF application, during the next two years the solution grows a lot.
It's around 70 different services.
We are using Windows Identity Foundation for security for majority, others use SSL and some don't have

I'm looking to restructure the application, I'am thinking about having multiple WCF application (one for business services, and other for backend services, etc...),
I think it can help for a lot for testing.

My question is:
Is there a way to construct a solution with multiple WCF applications without having to create and deploy multiple packages (not very usefull for deployments)
If I restucture the application, I will have 4 or 5 different services projects and also need an app.config file for each(not easy to maintain or upgrade in production environments)

Comment: perhaps you can merge you projects into a single dll before deploying?

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many service assemblies in a WCF host as you like just make sure they have unique names. Every service dll gets its own project and the host stays at one project in the solution. Then create an app.config like this:

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehaviour" name="DLSService.DLSService">
    <endpoint address="DLSService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      name="basicHttpDLS" contract="DLSService.IDLSService" />
    <endpoint binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="mexDLS"
      contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <endpoint address="DLSService" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      name="netTcpDLS" contract="DLSService.IDLSService" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/ServicesHost/DLSService" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehaviour" name="RopsPreorderService.RopsPreorderService">
    <endpoint address="RopsPreorderService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      name="basicHttpPreorderService" contract="PreorderService.IPreorderService" />
    <endpoint binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="mexRopsPreorderService"
      contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <endpoint address="PreorderService" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      name="netTcpPreorderService" contract="RopsPreorderService.IPreorderService" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/ServicesHost/PreorderService" />
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9000/PreorderService" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>      
</services>
```

Comment: @ Servé Laurijssen, when you say as many services as I want, you mean WCF Service application or WCF Service Library? I Found a solution on the net where the autor wrote a solution with multiple WCF service Library and use only one WCF service application but I'm not able to make the same thing...

Comment: *"You can have as many service assemblies in a WCF host as you like"* is not exactly correct.  A given service host can host a **single** service.  It can have many endpoints, but it can only host one service.  If you have multiple services in an application, you will have multiple service hosts - one for each service.  In your example above, you will have one service host for `DLSService` and another for `Rops PreorderService`.

Comment: I've just tested a solution with multiple WCF Service Libraries and only one WCF service Application for services presentation and it works fine

Comment: yes ok, conceptually its like many services in one host but technically its more like one host for every service

Comment: Yes, I prefer to have multiple WCF application, but it will be difficult for deployments